# Проблема с подключением динамической библиотеки и получением указателя на метод с использованием QLibrary

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, lib, dynamic

Как правильно подключить динамическую библиотеку к проекту и использовать определенные методы из нее с использованием класса `QLibrary`?

У меня есть следующий код, в котором я пытаюсь подключить динамическую библиотеку и вызвать определенный метод из нее:

```cpp
bool AgentManager::registerAgent(AgentSettings &settings) {
  QLibrary myLibrary("/opt/goinfre/werewolf/Documents/github/MonitoringSystem/agents/cpu_agent/libcpu_agent");
  if (!myLibrary.load()) {
    qDebug() << "Ошибка при загрузке библиотеки";
    qDebug() << myLibrary.errorString();
    return false;
  }

  using fn = Agent* (*)(const AgentSettings&);
  fn newbie = reinterpret_cast<fn>(myLibrary.resolve("create"));
  if (!newbie) {
    qDebug() << "Ошибка при регистрации агента";
    qDebug() << myLibrary.errorString();
    return false;
  }

  Agent * agent = newbie(settings);
  if (!agent) {
    qDebug() << "Ошибка при создании агента";
    return false;
  }

  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), m_data.size(), m_data.size());
  m_data.push_back(agent);
  endInsertRows();

  return true;
}
```

Используется класс `AgentManager`, который пытается загрузить динамическую библиотеку `libcpu_agent` и вызвать метод `create` из этой библиотеки. Однако, при вызове `myLibrary.resolve("create")` я получаю `nullptr` и выводится сообщение об ошибке "Ошибка при регистрации агента". `AgentManager` знает только класс `Agent` и должен использовать его как интерфейс для вызова `getMetrics`

Как я могу правильно подключить динамическую библиотеку и получить указатель на нужный метод? Что может быть причиной возникновения этой ошибки?

---

`cpu_agent.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "agent.h"

class CpuAgent final : public Agent {
 public:
  CpuAgent() = default;
  explicit CpuAgent(const AgentSettings &settings);
  ~CpuAgent() = default;

  static  Agent * create(const AgentSettings &settings);

  virtual const QHash<QString, Metric> & getMetrics() const override final;
};
```

`agent.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "agent_settings.h"

class Agent {
 public:
  Agent() = default;
  explicit Agent(const AgentSettings &settings);
  explicit Agent(const Agent & other) = delete;
  explicit Agent(Agent && other) = delete;
  virtual ~Agent() = default;

  Agent & operator=(const Agent & other) = delete;
  Agent & operator=(Agent && other) = delete;

  virtual const QHash<QString, Metric> & getMetrics() const = 0;
  
  const AgentSettings & getSettings() const;
  AgentSettings & getSettings();

 protected:
  AgentSettings m_settings;
};
```

`agent_settings.h`:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <QDir>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QHash>
#include <QPair>
#include <QString>
#include <QTime>
#include <QVariant>

enum class ComparisonOperator {
  kLessThan = 0,
  kLessThanOrEqualTo,
  kEqualTo,
  kGreaterThanOrEqualTo,
  kGreaterThan
};

struct Metric {
  QVariant value;
  ComparisonOperator op;
  QVariant comparisonValue;
};

struct AgentSettings {
  bool m_enabled;
  QString m_name;
  QString m_type;
  QTime m_interval;
  QFileInfo m_config;
  QElapsedTimer m_timer;
  QHash<QString, Metric> m_metrics;
};
```

CMake для сборки динамической библиотеки:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(cpu_agent VERSION 1.0.0 LANGUAGES CXX)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Core REQUIRED)

set(HEADERS
  cpu_agent.h
  ../agent/agent.h
  ../../settings/agent/agent_settings.h
)

set(SOURCES
  cpu_agent.cc
  ../agent/agent.cc
  ../../settings/agent/agent_settings.cc
)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
  ${HEADERS}
  ${SOURCES}
)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED ${PROJECT_SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../agent
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../settings/agent
)

set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    # PREFIX ""
    # SUFFIX .so
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../agents/${PROJECT_NAME}"
)

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME}
  PUBLIC
  cxx_std_17
)

target_compile_options(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE

    # -Wall
    # -Werror
    # -Wextra
    # -Wpedantic
    # -fsanitize=address
)

target_link_options(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE

    # -fsanitize=address
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC Qt6::Core)

# Копируем файл настроек в выходную директорию
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/setting.conf
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../agents/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

```
➜  MonitoringSystem git:(develop) ✗ nm -C agents/cpu_agent/libcpu_agent.dylib                                                                         
0000000000003f34 s GCC_except_table15
0000000000003f00 s GCC_except_table2
0000000000003f10 s GCC_except_table29
0000000000003f24 s GCC_except_table6
                 U __Unwind_Resume
                 U QArrayData::deallocate(QArrayData*, long long, long long)
0000000000003a00 T QArrayData::ref()
0000000000003720 T QArrayData::deref()
0000000000003160 T int QAtomicOps<int>::loadRelaxed<int>(std::__1::atomic<int> const&)
0000000000003a70 T bool QAtomicOps<int>::ref<int>(std::__1::atomic<int>&)
0000000000003220 T bool QAtomicOps<int>::deref<int>(std::__1::atomic<int>&)
0000000000003100 t QHashPrivate::Data<QHashPrivate::Node<QString, Metric> >::~Data()
0000000000003380 t QHashPrivate::Data<QHashPrivate::Node<QString, Metric> >::~Data()
0000000000003560 t QHashPrivate::Node<QString, Metric>::~Node()
0000000000003580 t QHashPrivate::Node<QString, Metric>::~Node()
0000000000003540 T QHashPrivate::Span<QHashPrivate::Node<QString, Metric> >::Entry::node()
0000000000003450 T QHashPrivate::Span<QHashPrivate::Node<QString, Metric> >::freeData()
0000000000003410 t QHashPrivate::Span<QHashPrivate::Node<QString, Metric> >::~Span()
0000000000003430 t QHashPrivate::Span<QHashPrivate::Node<QString, Metric> >::~Span()
0000000000003780 t AgentSettings::AgentSettings(AgentSettings const&)
00000000000037f0 t AgentSettings::AgentSettings(AgentSettings const&)
0000000000002f80 t AgentSettings::~AgentSettings()
0000000000002fb0 t AgentSettings::~AgentSettings()
00000000000036f0 T QTypedArrayData<char16_t>::deallocate(QArrayData*)
00000000000039d0 T QArrayDataPointer<char16_t>::ref()
0000000000003690 T QArrayDataPointer<char16_t>::deref()
0000000000003950 t QArrayDataPointer<char16_t>::QArrayDataPointer(QArrayDataPointer<char16_t> const&)
0000000000003980 t QArrayDataPointer<char16_t>::QArrayDataPointer(QArrayDataPointer<char16_t> const&)
0000000000003620 t QArrayDataPointer<char16_t>::~QArrayDataPointer()
0000000000003640 t QArrayDataPointer<char16_t>::~QArrayDataPointer()
00000000000036d0 T QArrayDataPointer<char16_t>::operator->()
0000000000003a30 T QBasicAtomicInteger<int>::ref()
0000000000003140 T QBasicAtomicInteger<int>::deref()
00000000000037b0 T Agent::getSettings()
0000000000003740 T Agent::Agent(AgentSettings const&)
0000000000002fa0 t Agent::~Agent()
0000000000002fa0 t Agent::~Agent()
0000000000002f50 t Agent::~Agent()
00000000000038f0 t QHash<QString, Metric>::QHash(QHash<QString, Metric> const&)
0000000000003bc0 t QHash<QString, Metric>::QHash(QHash<QString, Metric> const&)
0000000000003000 t QHash<QString, Metric>::~QHash()
0000000000003040 t QHash<QString, Metric>::~QHash()
00000000000035b0 t Metric::~Metric()
00000000000035d0 t Metric::~Metric()
00000000000038c0 t QString::QString(QString const&)
0000000000003920 t QString::QString(QString const&)
0000000000003020 t QString::~QString()
0000000000003600 t QString::~QString()
0000000000002e60 T CpuAgent::create(AgentSettings const&)
0000000000002e30 T CpuAgent::CpuAgent(AgentSettings const&)
0000000000002df0 T CpuAgent::CpuAgent(AgentSettings const&)
0000000000002f00 t CpuAgent::~CpuAgent()
0000000000002ee0 t CpuAgent::~CpuAgent()
0000000000002f30 t CpuAgent::~CpuAgent()
                 U QVariant::~QVariant()
                 U QFileInfo::QFileInfo(QFileInfo const&)
                 U QFileInfo::~QFileInfo()
00000000000036e0 T QtPrivate::QPodArrayOps<char16_t>::destroyAll()
0000000000003c00 T QtPrivate::RefCount::ref()
00000000000030b0 T QtPrivate::RefCount::deref()
0000000000003120 T QBasicAtomicInteger<int>::loadRelaxed() const
00000000000037d0 T Agent::getSettings() const
0000000000002ec0 T CpuAgent::getMetrics() const
0000000000003180 t std::__1::__atomic_base<int, false>::load(std::__1::memory_order) const
0000000000003c40 t std::__1::__atomic_base<int, false>::load(std::__1::memory_order) const
0000000000003ad0 t std::__1::__atomic_base<int, true>::fetch_add(int, std::__1::memory_order)
0000000000003280 t std::__1::__atomic_base<int, true>::fetch_sub(int, std::__1::memory_order)
0000000000003d10 t std::__1::__atomic_base<int, true>::fetch_sub(int, std::__1::memory_order)
0000000000003250 t std::__1::__atomic_base<int, true>::operator--()
0000000000003ce0 t std::__1::__atomic_base<int, true>::operator--()
0000000000003aa0 t std::__1::__atomic_base<int, true>::operator++()
00000000000031b0 t int std::__1::__cxx_atomic_load<int>(std::__1::__cxx_atomic_base_impl<int> const*, std::__1::memory_order)
0000000000003c70 t int std::__1::__cxx_atomic_load<int>(std::__1::__cxx_atomic_base_impl<int> const*, std::__1::memory_order)
0000000000003b00 t int std::__1::__cxx_atomic_fetch_add<int>(std::__1::__cxx_atomic_base_impl<int>*, int, std::__1::memory_order)
00000000000032b0 t int std::__1::__cxx_atomic_fetch_sub<int>(std::__1::__cxx_atomic_base_impl<int>*, int, std::__1::memory_order)
0000000000003d40 t int std::__1::__cxx_atomic_fetch_sub<int>(std::__1::__cxx_atomic_base_impl<int>*, int, std::__1::memory_order)
                 U std::terminate()
0000000000004040 S typeinfo for Agent
0000000000004050 S typeinfo for CpuAgent
0000000000003f4e S typeinfo name for Agent
0000000000003f44 S typeinfo name for CpuAgent
0000000000004068 s vtable for Agent
0000000000004018 S vtable for CpuAgent
                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info
                 U vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info
                 U operator delete[](void*)
                 U operator delete(void*)
                 U operator new(unsigned long)
0000000000003550 t ___clang_call_terminate
                 U ___cxa_begin_catch
                 U ___cxa_pure_virtual
                 U ___gxx_personality_v0
00000000000080d8 d __dyld_private
                 U dyld_stub_binder
```

Comment: а "create"  случайно не c++ фунция?

Comment: @PavelGridin   C++ да, если про название метода то оно уже было KKKK чтобы не было конфликтов

Comment: Библиотека не экспортирует функции `create`. В этой ситуации правильнее было бы использовать `QPlugin`.

Comment: @user7860670.   Поподробней можете расказать в чём суть, и почему не экспортируются функции

Comment: Удваиваю совет про `QPlugin`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот несколько аргументов, почему использование `QLibrary` и `extern "C"` может быть предпочтительным в некоторых случаях, особенно для агентов мониторинга системы:

1. **Простота использования**: Использование `QLibrary` и `extern "C"` предоставляет простой и понятный способ загрузки и подключения динамических библиотек. Вы можете использовать стандартные функции C++ для работы с объектами библиотеки, без необходимости вводить дополнительные зависимости или использовать сложные механизмы плагинов.
2. **Независимость от фреймворков**: Использование `QLibrary` позволяет избежать зависимости от фреймворков или специфичных для платформы механизмов плагинов, таких как `QPlugin`. Это особенно полезно, если вам необходимо подключать и использовать различные агенты мониторинга системы, которые могут быть разработаны с использованием разных фреймворков или библиотек.
3. **Переносимость**: Использование `extern "C"` вместе с `QLibrary` обеспечивает переносимость кода между различными компиляторами и платформами. Он создает стабильный ABI (Application Binary Interface), что означает, что библиотеки, скомпилированные с использованием одного компилятора, могут быть безопасно использованы с помощью других компиляторов без проблем с совместимостью.
4. **Гибкость**: Использование `extern "C"` позволяет вам предоставить чистый C-интерфейс для вашей библиотеки, что делает ее более доступной для других языков программирования. Это может быть полезно, если в будущем вы решите использовать агенты мониторинга системы из других языков или интегрировать их в существующие проекты, не написанные на C++.
5. **Упрощение сборки и развертывания**: Использование `QLibrary` и `extern "C"` позволяет сократить сложность сборки и развертывания вашего проекта. Вам не нужно настраивать сложные механизмы плагинов или дополнительные системы управления зависимостями. Вы можете просто скомпилировать библиотеки, загрузить их во время выполнения и использовать их, как требуется.

Несмотря на преимущества `QLibrary`  и `extern "C"`, каждый подход имеет свои сильные стороны и ограничения. Поэтому вам следует выбирать подход, который наиболее соответствует вашим требованиям и ограничениям проекта.

---

Добавил в #include "cpu_agent.cc"

```
extern "C" {
  Agent* __create(const AgentSettings settings) { return new CpuAgent(settings); }
}
```

Создал объект класса следующем образом

```
auto AgentManager::registerAgent(const QString &path, AgentSettings &settings) -> bool {
  QSharedPointer<QLibrary> library(new QLibrary(path));
  if (!library->load()) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to load library:" << library->errorString();
    return false;
  }

  using fn = Agent *(*)(const AgentSettings settings);
  fn __create = (fn)library->resolve("__create");
  if (!__create) {
    qDebug() << "Failed to resolve __create function";
    return false;
  }

  beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), m_data.size(), m_data.size());
  m_data.push_back({library, QSharedPointer<Agent>(__create(settings))});
  endInsertRows();

  return true;
}
```